# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create BackupAgent com.berlin.mobson.view.OsmandBackupAgent: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

Some users have reported this error via the android error reporting popup thing but I have no idea what causes it. I googled but I can't find any good leads.

Anyone know what causes this error?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create BackupAgent
com.berlin.mobson.view.OsmandBackupAgent:
java.lang.NullPointerException at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateBackupAgent(ActivityThread.java:2331)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:134) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) at

dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException at
android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:377)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:320) at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateBackupAgent(ActivityThread.java:2301)
... 10 more
```

My App is a Place finder that uses google Places api to get search results. (no the library, just the json urls)

Comment: Is this [com.berlin.mobson.view](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.berlin.mobson.view&hl=en) your own app or does your own app rely on it?

Comment: @yorkw no my app has nothing to do with that. But I have just emailed the developer of that app, maybe he can shed some light. thanks

Answer (score 0):

osmand is 
Mobile Map Viewing & Navigation for Offline and Online OSM Maps.

The source code is available here [Osmand](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/checkout)

May be you can remove osmand from the device and then debug the application using above code available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like their BackupAgent implementation is having some problems.  A temporary solution is unchecking "Back up my data" in settings->backup & reset.  Long term the NPE has to be tracked down in the BackupAgent.